# Pulling Text from an edittext and using it for an android notification

Tags: android, string, notifications, android-edittext

I'm trying to make a simple app for android that allows users to make custom notification reminders.  I'm fairly new to programming and am having trouble pulling the text from the edittext widgets and using them in the notification.  I have tried some methods that people have posted in response to similar questions but they have not worked.  Pleas look at my code and try to help

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
Button   mButton;
EditText mTitle;
EditText mContent;



public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    mTitle   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
    mContent   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editContent);


    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Reminder Created";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = MainActivity.this.mTitle.getText().toString();
    CharSequence contentText = MainActivity.this.mContent.getText().toString();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


    final Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);


    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);


    Button statusbarnotify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    statusbarnotify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);




        }
    });   
}    



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code as far as I see, but the problem is you do all the stuff inside `onCreate`.

`onCreate` method is only called on the creation of the activity, as the name suggests. Since there is no input at the create time, your `contentTitle` and `contentText` will be empty strings and notification will not appear as desired.

To solve this problem, you need to get the text from your edittext widgets and create the notification inside `onClick` method of the button you placed. In other words, you need to carry all these stuff you created

```
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
CharSequence tickerText = "Reminder Created";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = mTitle.getText().toString();
CharSequence contentText = mContent.getText().toString();
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);


final Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);


String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
final NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
```

inside `onClick` method you override before you notify the notification manager.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Tank you so much.  This was a big help as I am new to programming.